# Migration from Access to MySQL using Access as front end

Tags: ms-access

I have an ACCESS database(.accdb) with tables, forms, queries, reports , modules and microsoft access class objects(VBA code). Now the requirement is to shift from access to optional database. The options that I could find by browsing are using either MySQL or SQL Server. As of now, I would like to use Access as front end to any back end database. I would like to know more detailed information regarding migration from Access to optional database. Can anyone please help me or point me to good resources.

Answer (score 1):

I've used SQL Server as a backend for an Access front-end app in the past with pretty decent success. You can use the [SQL Server Migration Assistant wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28763) to migrate the data from an Access Database to a SQL Server database.

Performing a quick search for "*using SQL Server database as back-end for MS Access*" will yield a number of resources on things to consider and do. You can also refer to this SO Question [Can a Microsoft Access Forms application be switched to work with a SQL back end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495734/can-a-microsoft-access-forms-application-be-switched-to-work-with-a-sql-back-end?rq=1) for additional insight.

My experience has been pretty positive with this sort of migration, but it really depends upon how you've designed and constructed the application. It could be a very simple migration (a few hours to tweak and test things) to a much larger effort on your part to make sure everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server (Express) as backend using export data from Access Menu. If you will use MySQL some features like auto_increment fields don't work fine and it will need to write VBA code to work as expected.